# How to use KoolPHP Suite in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

hi i am using KoolPHP suite for UI components like grid, tree, calander, tabs to use in cakephp. But some how they are appearing on the webpage but are not accessible. Does any one have idea how to make it work. This is my code to use KoolPHP Tabs:

```
<?php
                require "vendors/KoolControls/KoolTabs/kooltabs.php";
                $kts = new KoolTabs("kts");
                $kts->styleFolder = "vendors/KoolControls/KoolTabs/styles/silver";

                $kts->addTab("root", "dashboard", "Dashboard", "", true);

                $kts->addTab("root", "admin", "Admin", "admin");

                $kts->addTab("root", "setup", "Setup", "setup");
                $kts->addTab("setup", "users", "Users", "");
                $kts->addTab("setup", "warehouses", "Warehouses", "");
                $kts->addTab("setup", "brands", "Brands", "");
                $kts->addTab("setup", "pos", "POS", "");

                $kts->addTab("root", "stock", "Stock", "stock");
                $kts->addTab("root", "products", "Products", "product");
                $kts->addTab("root", "reports", "Reports", "report");
                $kts->addTab("root", "orders", "Orders", "orders");
                $kts->addTab("root", "help", "Help", "help");

                echo $kts->Render();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So stupid. The problem was with URL rewriting in CakePHP's .htaccess file and now everything works fine. Sorry for bothering you guys.